# Why R system is not able to execute hdfs commands?

Tags: r, hdfs, system

I am trying to merge some .csv files with the
`hdfs dfs -getmerge /path/folderfile filename.csv` command.
If I run this command from a terminal or from rstudio's internal terminal, it works fine. If I execute the same command using `system("hdfs dfs -getmerge /path/folderfile /destinationpath/filename.csv")` it returns the following error:

```
sh: hdfs: command not found
Warning message:
In system("hdfs dfs -getmerge /path/folderfile /destinationpath/filename.csv") :
  error in running command
```

Thanks for suggestions